# ng-repeat nested array in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm having issues outputting the nested array in my app.js file.
I can get the outer array to output, but the reviews for the book won't render on the screen. How can I get the nested array to output under the title.
Here's what I have so far.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('DirectivesTest', []);
app.directive('bookReviews', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'book-reviews.html',
        controller: 'BookController'
     //controller function
}; //end return
}) //end directive



app.controller("BookController",  function($scope){
$scope.books = [{


title: "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
description: "Harry Potter has no idea how famoushe  is. That's because he's being raised by his miserable aunt and uncle who are terrified Harry will learn that he's really a wizard, just as his parents were. But everything changes when Harry is summoned to attend an infamous school for wizards, and he begins to discover some clues about his illustrious birthright. From the surprising way he is greeted by a lovable giant, to the unique curriculum and colorful faculty at his unusual school, Harry finds himself drawn deep inside a mystical world he never knew existed and closer to his own noble destiny.",

review: [{


stars: 5,
body: "I love this book!",
author: "JoeJohnson@gmail.com",
createdOn: 42434343

},
{

stars: 4,
body: "It was pretty good. A little long though",
author: "PaulPaulson@gmail.com",
createdOn: 42434343 
},
{
stars: 5,
body: "It's the best book I've ever read.",
author: "JimJohnson@gmail.com",
createdOn: 454535543

}
]
        }];

})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DirectivesTest">
<head>
    <title>Directives Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
The #1 Book Review Site With Only 6 Books!
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div ng-controller="BookController">
    <div class="test" ng-repeat="book in books">
{{book.title}}
<div ng-repeat="bookReview in books.review">
{{bookReview.review}}
</div> <!--End parent ng-repeat-->

</div>      
</div>



</div>

</div>
<book-reviews></book-reviews>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are your closing </div>'s correct? It looks like you're not closing the inner ``ng-repeat``. In addition - ``bookReview`` doesn't have a ``.review`` property. You'll want to use ``bookReview.body`` (or any of the other available keys that exist within a review).

Comment: You have a typo. In second ng-repeat you have written bookReview in books.review. There should be book.review because that's this one book that has reviews

Comment: Thank you Alex and Daniel. I was missing the closing div and now it outputs with bookReview.body

Answer (score 1):

it should be

`<div ng-repeat="bookReview in book.review">` not

`<div ng-repeat="bookReview in books.review">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="BookController">
  <div class="test" ng-repeat="book in books">
    {{ book.title }}
    <div ng-repeat="review in book.review">
      {{ review.body }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is because the first ng-repeat takes each item form $scope.books which creates a book instance. Then you have a **nested** repeater that repeater have to use the parent instance from the original array of items. Which in this case is `book`.

Consider this pseudo code:

```
each item in array
  each subitem in item
```

Initially you created this pseudo code:

```
each item in array
  each subitem in array.item
```

which when you write it out like this makes it obvious what you error was.